# How to configure Chrome on a Terminal Server

Tags: group-policy, terminal-server, google-chrome

I have installed Google Chrome on a Windows 2003 Terminal Server and I now want to configure it for the users. How do I do that? For example clear cookies when browser close, set favorites and the home page, restrict access to the setting options, etc

How do I do that?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/126299

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google has a set of group policy templates available. That would be the best way to enforce the settings you want on either the machine or user level.

Downloads for the ADM template can be found [here](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates) and more details on the actual policy objects that can be set is found [here.](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3)

Comment: +1: I did not know that there were ADM/ADMX templates for Chrome.